# Запуск mono через supervisor, программно

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, mono, supervisord

Привет. В общем надо запустить через supervisor парочку приложений написанных на c# с передачей аргументов и заставить их автоматически перезапускаться при выкидыше.

Допустим: сейчас запускаю через screen. Но когда приложение выкидывает, то сессия в screen закрывается, нужно чтобы перезапускалось. Использую для этого:

---

`var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

```
exec('screen -dmLS client_1 mono /var/www/clients.exe ' + ip + ' ' + port + ' > /var/www/1_log.txt');
```

---

Нашел модуль под Node-JS - **node-supervisor**

Но думаю, что он запускает только .js скрипты.

---

**Что хотелось бы узнать?
Что подошло бы под мое описание и желательно с примерами!**

---

Стоит Ubuntu x32 (16.04). ***Большое спасибо.***

Answer (score 0):

У supervisord'а все конфиг файлы хранятся в `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` директории, если вы правильно всё настроили. То есть, положите там конфиг файл, к примеру, `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp.conf` примерно с таким содержанием:

```
[program:myapp]
command=nohup mono /var/www/clients.exe 127.0.0.1  8080 > /var/www/1_log.txt
autostart=true
stdout_logfile_backups=5
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/www/1_log.txt
stdout_logfile=/var/www/1_log.txt
environment=SECRET_PASSPHRASE='это секрет',SECRET_TWO='второй секрет'
```